# How can i run an a window width "Hello world" on Kivy?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I am new programming in kivy, i'm trying to run the classic "hello world" window,  using pycharm comunity edition, in ubuntu 18.04 and when I do it the window does not appear but in the output I get the following message:

The code:

```
# -*-coding:utf-8;-*-
import  kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from  kivy.uix.label import Label

class myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hola Mundo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp().run()
```

And the result is:

```
/home/capobugbler/PycharmProjects/dj1/venv/bin/python /home/capobugbler/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch.py
[1, 5, 7, 8]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

widthout any "hello world" window
but if i run the same code in a terminal, the "hello world" window appears after so time.
the version of pycharm that i use is CE2017.3 and y run this into a scrath file for the moument, and if this can help, i don't know why i'm runing  this into an a virtual environment created for a django proyect.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure you're running in the helloworld script? What is the name of the .py?

Comment: looks like you're running the wrong file

Comment: hello, I just copy the code given on page 54 of chapter 8 in the last documentation of kivy given by "readthedocs" with the purpose of seeing if it worked, it works in console, but inside pycharm not

Comment: I wrote the code in a scrath file in pycharm, I assumed that would not affect